# How to merge array of objects in single array and leave wanted values TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How to get single object from this array of objects, and if there is true in some of the property it should be set to true.

For example if BILLING_CYCLE for view property has true in one of objects the returned object should have true value.

As you see groups can be nested, so recursion is needed.
These are interfaces of object

```
interface UserPermissions {
  [key: string]: UserPermission;
}
interface UserPermission {
  view: boolean;
  modify: boolean;
  delete?: boolean;
  additionalActions?: { [key: string]: boolean };
  groups?: { [key: string]: UserPermission };
}
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    "BILLING": {
      "view": false,
      "modify": false,
      "additionalActions": {},
      "groups": {
        "BILLING_CYCLE": {
          "view": false,
          "modify": false,
          "additionalActions": {
            "CONFIRM": false
          },
          "groups": {}
        },
        "ACCOUNT": {
          "view": false,
          "modify": false,
          "additionalActions": {},
          "groups": {}
        },
        "ADMIN": {
          "view": true,
          "modify": true,
          "additionalActions": {},
          "groups": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "BILLING": {
      "view": true,
      "modify": true,
      "additionalActions": {},
      "groups": {
        "BILLING_CYCLE": {
          "view": true,
          "modify": true,
          "additionalActions": {
            "CONFIRM": true
          },
          "groups": {}
        },
        "ACCOUNT": {
          "view": true,
          "modify": true,
          "additionalActions": {},
          "groups": {}
        },
        "ADMIN": {
          "view": false,
          "modify": false,
          "additionalActions": {},
          "groups": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

const expectation = {
"BILLING": {
      "view": true,
      "modify": true,
      "additionalActions": {},
      "groups": {
        "BILLING_CYCLE": {
          "view": true,
          "modify": true,
          "additionalActions": {
            "CONFIRM": true
          },
          "groups": {}
        },
        "ACCOUNT": {
          "view": true,
          "modify": true,
          "additionalActions": {},
          "groups": {}
        },
        "ADMIN": {
          "view": true,
          "modify": true,
          "additionalActions": {},
          "groups": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. Could you provide an example with expected output?

Comment: @NeyazAhmad added expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a merging function, say, `mergePermissions()`, then call [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the input, merging each object with the accumulator object recursively.

For each property, we'll keep the existing value, unless it is a boolean. If so, we'll perform an `or` comparison (||), so if either if true then result will also be true.

```js
const data = [ { "BILLING": { "view": false, "modify": false, "additionalActions": {}, "groups": { "BILLING_CYCLE": { "view": false, "modify": false, "additionalActions": { "CONFIRM": false }, "groups": {} }, "ACCOUNT": { "view": false, "modify": false, "additionalActions": {}, "groups": {} }, "ADMIN": { "view": true, "modify": true, "additionalActions": {}, "groups": {} } } } }, { "BILLING": { "view": true, "modify": true, "additionalActions": {}, "groups": { "BILLING_CYCLE": { "view": true, "modify": true, "additionalActions": { "CONFIRM": true }, "groups": {} }, "ACCOUNT": { "view": true, "modify": true, "additionalActions": {}, "groups": {} }, "ADMIN": { "view": false, "modify": false, "additionalActions": {}, "groups": {} } } } } ] 

function mergePermissions(obj1, obj2) {
    let result = {};
    for(let k in obj1) {
        if (obj1[k] && typeof(obj1[k]) === 'object') { 
            result[k] = mergePermissions(obj1[k], (obj2?.[k])) ;
        } else if ((typeof(obj1[k]) === 'boolean') && (typeof(obj2?.[k]) === 'boolean')) { 
            result[k] = obj1[k] || (obj2?.[k]);
        } else { 
            result[k] = obj1[k];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let result = data.reduce((acc, el) => { 
    return mergePermissions(el, acc);
}, {})

console.log('Result:', result);
```

Comment: Just had to apply typescript types to it